# Auto turn off during power outage

Tags: power

how to make extension that Auto turn off switch when brownout? to prevent power spikes. do you have any diagram? thankyou
this is for my pc, ref and aircondition. thankyou

Comment: A latching relay should do that - latches on and resets to off if the power goes down.

Comment: You can buy switches that do that. They're used in workshops to control machines that you don't want starting by themselves after a power failure, like drills and bandsaws. Switches like [these](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/?searchTerm=no+volt+switch) . Good search terms are 'no volt', or 'restart protection'

Answer (score 1):

An electromagnetic relay or a contactor would suffice.

[image]

When the 'on' button is actuated, the relay latches and the appliance is on.

When the 'off' button is actuated or the power fails, the relay resets and the appliance is off.

Comment: The power is described as a "brownout", not a blackout. The relay would likely still be held.